# I am trying to overload the main method but I am getting following error in cmd

Tags: java, overloading, program-entry-point

filename: mainoverloading.java

error: could not find or load main class mainoverloading

```
class simple{
    public static void main(int a)
    {
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Hi");
        main(10);   
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class is named `simple` (not `mainoverloading`). Rename the class (or move the file "mainoverloading.java" to "simple.java").

Comment: thanks That worked. But will it be always necessary to have class name same as file name even if I declared it as 
class simple { } instead of public class simple{ }

Comment: A class can have an inner class, but the outer class must follow that naming convention. At least to use any java compiler I know.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  does Java allow us to use any name for file name, when class is not public?

Comment: @tnadeV The java compiler has to find the class (and it's dependencies) to compile it. If you deviate from the naming convention, then you'll need to resolve those dependencies manually. Such is possible (in general), but inherently more complex than using the default rules (and not really advisable with a `main` method). See also [JLS-12.1. JVM Startup](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1)

Answer (score 0):

> Java allow us to use any name for file name, only when class is not public.
>   [image]

Its running nicely, because for eclipse main class it simple, its smart to identify that simple.class will be created.

If you are running from command line ,
class file created for your code is **simple.class**  so JVM will be unable to find mainoverlading.class

Answer (score 0):

When You compile the above given class using

```
javac mainoverloading.java
```

It is successfully compiled and a class file named **simple.class** is generated in your folder.

You can then run it by typing 
`java simple`.

But this is actually not a good practice, as Elliott Frisch said rename your class into **simple.java.**

have a look For Windows- [HelloWorld](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html)

For Linux - [HelloWorld](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/unix.html)